# Como puedo configurar MAMP para ver los errores al estar ejecutando los códigos de PHP, como errores fatales?

Tags: php

al estar ejecutando un código hecho en PHP necesito que mande los errores los cuales tengo como "ERRORES FATALES", para validar en donde está dicho problema y poder corregirlo, ya que no puedo verlo.

Comment: Bienvenido..Juan Yi..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado o investigado más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Por cierto busca en el sitio, en ocasiones se tiene la información que buscas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=display_errors

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo de php antes de cualquier cosa añade estas instrucciones

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

O en tu php.ini busca esta línea y modificala así

```
display_errors = on
```

Recuerda que estas instrucciones se recomiendan no se implementen si estamos en producción, por que obviamente les saldrá a los consumidores de tu app/pág.

Comment: Hay información en el sitio acerca de esto . saludos: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=display_errors